# TamperMonkey on Chrome[beginner]

Tags: google-calendar, tampermonkey

I'm trying to make a countertop/wall calendar for my house and want to remove some features to keep others from easily getting to different parts of my google account. when I call the first remove statement alone it works but as soon as I call the second neither works.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Google Wall Calender
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Remove links to other sections of google for displaying wall calnder
// @author       You
// @match        https://calendar.google.com/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=google.com
// @grant        none
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

    document.getElementsByClassName('gb_Vd gb_Xa gb_Kd')[0].remove
   // document.getElementsByClassName('Kk7lMc-DWWcKd-OomVLb-haAclf gboEAb')[0].remove


();
```

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will break as soon as Google pushes some updates to the Calendar UI. These classes don't look fixed - they are generated randomly for each build.